# How to remove time slots that has an event or outside the "businessHours" ? ( on "timeGridDay")

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I want to remove or hide time slots that has an event or out of businnessHours on timeGridDay view. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Assuming your business hours are consistent every day, you could use the minTime and maxTime settings (see the documentation for details)

Comment: You can't remove times which have events though. The whole point of having events is so you can display them in the calendar! If you want people to know that those times are unavailable then the presence of an existing event should be sufficient to indicate that

Comment: P.s. if minTime/maxTime doesn't work for you (because you have different business hours on different days) then you can always use the selectConstraint and/or eventConstraint options to stop people putting events outside the business hours. Again, you can read about it in the documentation

Comment: Thanks for your interest. minTime/maxTime doesn't work for me.
Actually I wanna show only available(has no events) time slots. Is it impossible?

Or there is one more thing that works for me... 
Writing something like "not available" for all time slots that are unavailable, including that aren't business hours

Comment: How can I do this? 

I've tried, eventRender but it's only wrote to first timeslot in multislot events. and it's not work for non business hour slots

Comment: "I wanna show only available(has no events) time slots" ...yes, it's impossible. I already explained this. But it doesn't matter. The fact that an event is in that slot will tell the user that the slot is not available. You can colour them red if you like to emphasise it. You could set the title of every event to "Unavailable" if you like. Anything you want which will make it 100% clear what the meaning of the event is.

Comment: " I've tried, eventRender but it's only wrote to first timeslot in multislot events" ...I can't fix a vague description of a problem. Show me the event data, show me your calendar config, show me your eventRender method. Then there's a chance to fix it.

Comment: " it's not work for non business hour slots" ...unless your non-business-hour slots have events in them, then obviously it would not work because eventRender only affects events. But the non-business-hour slots are already a different colour, so it should be clear already that they are not available. Again you could alter that  colour via CSS if you like. And as I said, you can also prevent users from selecting them.

Comment: It's clear enough. Thanks for your help...